# How to use a std::unique_ptr of a struct inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, struct, unique-ptr

How do I use a `std::unique_ptr` of a struct inside a class? Something like this, for example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

int main(void)
{
    struct a_struct
    {
        char a_char;
    };

    class A_class
    {
    public:
        A_class()
        {
            this->my_ptr.a_char = 'A';
        }
        void A_class_function()
        {
            printf("%c\n",this->my_ptr.a_char);
        }
        ~A_class()
        {

        }
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<a_struct> my_ptr(new a_struct);
    };

    A_class My_class;

    My_class.A_class_function();

    My_class.~A_class();

    return(0);
}
```

When compiling, it returns this error that I am not sure what to make of:

```
ptr_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ptr_test.cpp:27:39: error: expected identifier before ‘new’
  std::unique_ptr<a_struct> my_ptr(new a_struct);
                                   ^~~
ptr_test.cpp:27:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘new’
ptr_test.cpp: In constructor ‘main()::A_class::A_class()’:
ptr_test.cpp:16:14: error: invalid use of member function ‘std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct> main()::A_class::my_ptr(int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
    this->my_ptr.a_char = 'A';
    ~~~~~~^~~~~~
ptr_test.cpp: In member function ‘void main()::A_class::A_class_function()’:
ptr_test.cpp:20:28: error: invalid use of member function ‘std::unique_ptr<main()::a_struct> main()::A_class::my_ptr(int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
    printf("%c\n",this->my_ptr.a_char);
```

How do I fix this? How am I supposed to do something like this?

Comment: Don't call the destructor manually! It will be called automatically after that, and calling it twice is simply wrong.

Comment: The only time it is legal to call a destructor manually is when an object was constructed using [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). Which yours is not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to pointers and classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first error, you can't initialize class members inside the class declaration using the constructor syntax you are trying to use.

Use curly braces instead of parenthesis:

```cpp
class A_class
{
    ...

private:
    std::unique_ptr<a_struct> my_ptr{new a_struct};
};
```

Or, if you have a C++14 compiler:

```cpp
class A_class
{
    ...

private:
    std::unique_ptr<a_struct> my_ptr = std::make_unique<a_struct>();
};
```

Otherwise, use the `A_class` constructor's member initialization list instead:

```cpp
class A_class
{
public:
    A_class() : my_ptr(new a_struct)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

private:
    std::unique_ptr<a_struct> my_ptr;
};
```

For the other errors, `a_char` is a member of `a_struct`, not `std::unique_ptr`, so you need to access it using `my_ptr->a_char` instead of `my_ptr.a_char`.

```cpp
this->my_ptr->a_char = 'A';
...
printf("%c\n", this->my_ptr->a_char);
```